# Jmeter: Comparison of multiple result for result response with JDBC variables

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

In j meter: In a bean-shell assertion or any other I want to match the content of response which I have fetched using Jason extractor suppose:

```
Result[1]=A, Result[2]=b, Result[3]=c
```

and so on Versus variables I have fetched using JDBC pre-processor which has saved as:

```
Result_1=, Result_2=B, Result_3=c.
```

I am able to match 1 variable at a time but not all at one time. so need help with bean-shell code to compare all result at once.

Comment: Add your test plan/what you done so far to question

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) somewhere to your test plan (normally as a child of a [Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) you would like to fail)
2. Put the following code into "Script" area

   ```
   for (int i = 1; i <= Integer.parseInt(vars.get('ResultFromJSON_matchNr')); i++) {
       if (!vars.get('ResultFromJSON' + i).equals(vars.get('ResultFromJDBC_' + i))) {
           AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
           AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Variables mismatch')
       }
   }
   ```
3. Make sure you have `groovy` selected as the "Language" and have `Cache compiled script if available` box ticked

The above script assumes `ResultFromJSON` and `ResultFromJDBC` JMeter Variables reference names, amend them according to your real definitions.

More information: [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)